# Is it possible to use GetSellerList to get all the items listed by a different seller?

Tags: ebay-api

I am looking for a way to get all the items listed by a different seller. While this is possible to do through the eBay Browse API, there is a delay of a few minutes from when a seller lists an item to when it is visible in the eBay search.

As such, I am looking for a method to return all the items a particular seller (that is not me) has listed that will return the most up to date results.

I have found the https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html method, but I am not certain if it is possible to use it on other sellers. Can I use this method or is there another method that can achieve the required functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under the title of the linked url it is written:

> Use this call to retrieve items listed by the **authenticated user**, including item data.

therefore it is clearly not possibile

you could use finding API setting in the filter the username of the seller and get the list of (almost) all the item sold by such seller with few details:

if you need full details then you need to call getItem for each itemID retrieved by finding API

but since eBay released some years ago new APis, if you have to start a new project it can be wise not using the old trading APIs (and also Finding??) that though not deprecated yet, they might be soon